# Makefile : fclean gives error if program is not yet built

Tags: makefile

I have 2 makefiles that crash when I use the command `make re` if the program (or library) is not yet previously built, because `make re` calls `fclean`, which should remove the file and crashes if the file is not found. Here is one of the makefiles for a library

```
NAME = lib.a

CC = cc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
SRC = *.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

INC = Includes

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME):
    @$(CC) -I $(INC) $(CFLAGS) -c $? $(SRC)
    @ar rc $(NAME) $? $(OBJ)
    @ranlib $(NAME)

clean:
    @/bin/rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    @/bin/rm $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

when I call make re and lib.a still doesnt exist I get

```
rm: lib.a: No such file or directory
make: *** [fclean] Error 1
```

Is there anyway to get it to just ignore the `fclean` command if `lib.a` is not found?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Errors in Recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors) section of the GNU make manual for how to deal with this at the make level.

In this instance, however, you can also deal with this at the `rm` level. The `-f` flag to `rm` will cause it ignore non-existent files (as well as not prompting for deletion and in basically all other ways not stopping or returning a failure... ever).

That being said it shouldn't, in general, ever be necessary to clean before a new build. That generally seems necessary when a makefile is incorrectly written (as yours is) to not properly teach make what the dependencies between sources and targets are (and/or by not using targets essentially at all and always just building from scratch as you are).

Comment: I need 7 minutes to accept your answer. Thanks :)
Do you have any tips on where I could study to write a better makefile?

Comment: The manual is a good (though a bit dense and terse) read. There are makefile tutorials out there but most of them are of mediocre quality (at best). John Graham-Cumming recently updated his [The Gnu Make Book](http://www.nostarch.com/gnumake) which I've only read a little bit of but which I fully expect will be fantastic (his blog posts/etc. about make have been great for years). Ultimately, the core idea is that you teach make how to create an output file from all its input files and then just let make handle things.